# Meta_Query refuses to return results

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I am attempting to return posts for a specific query.
Using the following code:

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'tic_assignment',
        'value'   => $current_user -> ID,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'tic_department',
        'value'   => $_depts,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
);
$_args = array ( 'post_type' => 'tickets',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $_args );
```

Now, instead of returning my posts based on the query added, it still returns every post.

I have `var_dump`ed `$the_query` and what is returned is here: https://pastebin.com/PPYaJpSu

(It's just too big to paste it all here)

Even if I take out the second array, it still returns everything... when it should not return anything based on the `tic_assignment`

When I modify the arguments to:

```
$_args = array ( 'post_type' => 'tickets',
    'meta_key' => 'tic_assignment',
    'meta_value' => $current_user -> ID,
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $_args );
```

The proper query is constructed, and the proper results are returned.

What gives?

Comment: NOTE: `$current_user -> ID` and `$_depts` are populated properly, and are not throwing any kind of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `meta_query` key in your `$args`.

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'tic_assignment',
        'value'   => $current_user -> ID,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'tic_department',
        'value'   => $_depts,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
);
$_args = array ( 'post_type' => 'tickets',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $_args );
```

Comment: I thought that as well, and added it right after I posted the question.  No difference

Comment: Can you show how you're showing results ? Are you using the `$the_query->have_posts()` ?

Comment: Yes.  Besides that, as shown in the pastebin, I am `var_dump`ing `$the_query`, and the query in it shows the meta_query is NOT getting added to it, when using the `meta_query`.  It does, however, get modified if I use just `meta_key`, `meta_value`

Comment: if worse comes to worse, i can always dump to: `$wpdb->get_results` and write the custom query I need for this, was just really hoping to not have to go that route ;)